# C++ << operator overloading without friend function

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

Exactly as the topic says. Is there a possibility to do that? I was able to achieve this in overloading '+' operator, however, I could not do this with '<<' operator.

This is an example of code that works for me with friend function:

```
class Punkt2D
{
    int x,y;

    public:
        Punkt2D(int wartoscX, int wartoscY) : x(wartoscX), y(wartoscY) {}
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Punkt2D& punkt);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Punkt2D& punkt)
{
    out << "(" << punkt.x << ", " << punkt.y << ")" << endl; 
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Punkt2D p1(10,15);

    cout << p1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this code on '+' without befriending the function. Is it also possible for other operators? Maybe it is a silly question, however I am quite new to C++ and could not find any resource on the topic :(

```
class Vector
{
    public:

    double dx, dy;
    Vector() {dx=0; dy=0;}
    Vector(double x, double y) 
    {
        cout << "Podaj x " << endl;
        cin >>x;
        cout << "Podaj y " << endl;
        cin >> y;
        dx = x; dy = y;

    }
    Vector operator+ (Vector v);
};


Vector Vector::operator+ (Vector v)
{
    Vector tmpVector;
    tmpVector.dx = dx +v.dx;
    tmpVector.dy = dy+ v.dy;
    return tmpVector;
}

int main()
{
    double d,e;

    Vector a(d,e);
    Vector b(d,e);
    Vector c;
    c = a +b;
    cout<<endl << c.dy << " " << c.dx;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the function only calls `public` member functions of the class (or accesses `public` data members, if any) it does not need to be a friend.

Your `Vector` example is only accessing `public` members, hence it works.

Your `Punkt2D` is accessing `private` members, so the operator needs to be a friend.

Comment: Ok, I got puzzled a bit, as the answers seems to be contradictive.

What would the line of code look like to make it without befriending the function if all the members of the class were public?

I am interested only in lines with ostream element, i.e. the declaration and definition of the function.

Comment: A declaration of the form `std::ostream& operator<<(std:: ostream& out, const Punkt2D& punkt)` after the class declaration will do, since it is not a member of the class (e.g. in a header file).   The definition (i.e. implementation) of the `operator<<()` (which needs to be somewhere, but does not need to be in the header unless it is to be inlined) then needs to avoid accessing `private` or `protected members` of the class.

Comment: Thank you Peter :)

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be a friend to access the private members.

In the `Vector` the members are public, so that's different.

Answer (score 1):

The stream operators:

```
operator << output
operator >> input
```

When you use these as stream operators (rather than binary shift) the first parameter is a stream. Since you do not have access to the stream object (its not yours to modify) these can not be member operators they have to be external to the class. Thus they must either be friends of the class or have access to a public method that will do the streaming for you.